# UITableView with child cells (Tree Structure)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I'm trying to implement a custom tableview which when tapped on a cell should expand and display its child cells, which further might have their children. Tapping again on the cell should collapse the view.

My data model looks something like below:

```
var objectTree = [
    MyObject(name: "Parent 1", id: "1", parentId: nil, children: [MyObject(name: "Child 1", id: "2", parentId: "1"), MyObject(name: "Child 2", id: "3", parentId: "1"),]),
    MyObject(name: "Parent 2", id: "4", parentId: nil, children: [MyObject(name: "Child 3", id: "5", parentId: "4", children: [MyObject(name: "Grandchild 1", id: "6", parentId: "5")])])
]
```

Here, "Parent 1" is the first cell, when tapped on it should expand and display its children "Child 1" & "Child 2" as sub/child cells under the "Parent 1" cell forming a tree-like structure.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Currently my code in `didSelectRowAt` looks something like below:

```
var expandedRows = Set<Int>()
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let object = objectTree[indexPath.row]
        
        if let children = object.children {
            let isExpanded = expandedRows.contains(indexPath.row)
            
            if isExpanded {
                // Collapse the cell
                expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)
                let childRows = indexPath.row+1..<indexPath.row+1+children.count
                objectTree.removeSubrange(childRows)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: childRows.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .fade)
            } else {
                // Expand the cell
                expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)
                let childRows = children.enumerated().map({ IndexPath(row: indexPath.row+$0.offset+1, section: 0) })
                objectTree.insert(contentsOf: children, at: indexPath.row+1)
                tableView.insertRows(at: childRows, with: .fade)
            }
        }
    }
```

But the catch here is, tapping on expanded parent cell only collapses its direct child cells and not nest/grand child cells. Also as it involves `insert` & `deleteRows` the function is prone to execution errors or crashes. So need a better solution to this.

Comment: `UICollectionView`’s diffable data source has support for this kind of hierarchical expanding/collapsing. A list style collection view looks just like a table view. You would need to convert your code to use a diffable data source and collection view but then would be able to add support for expanding sections. The expanding/collapsing was discussed here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10045

Comment: Thanks @Geoff Hackworth for your help!

I'm trying to implement Modern Collection Views from the Apple Developer documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views. What I need is expandable/collapsible cells just like in the OutlineViewController but with custom Xib cells. Somehow I'm able to display my Xib cell in the collection view but it is no expanding/collapsing need some help on how to proceed further.